# trigger to save data when fails INSERT on another table?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've been googling for a while and found no answer for this question.

Consider this, I have a table `test_table(id serial, name varchar(15), surname varchar(40))`. If someone tries to **insert a value higher than 15 characters** in the column `name`, it will return **permission denied**.

What I need to know is if there is a way to create a `trigger` that anytime it **fails to insert** on that `test_table`, it saves (**inserts**) all the "lost" data in another table (maybe like) `log_failed_inserts(failedid int, failedname text, failedsurname text)`.

Please refrain answering stuff like "just increase the column limit" because that was just an example. I need to know if there is a way to log the data on failed INSERT commands.

**Edit:** Just to be clearer as the above sentence wasn't enough. No matter what error occurs when inserting, being 'invalid data type', 'length too big', 'you do not have permission to insert' (maybe not this last one), I want to log that something/someone tried to **insert the values X, Y, Z on the table `test_table` and it failed**.

Comment: yes, just create a trigger function with `if length(NEW."name") >15 then insert into log_failed_inserts select NEW... return null;` and create a trigger on the table that runs that fn()

Comment: Guys, you're failing to see the point... the character limit was just an example and even the error, it doesn't matter if the error is "permission denied" or "value too long"... I want a trigger that will log all values whatever is the error that occur when inserting, being access permission, length, wrong type of argument... I'll include that on the question

Comment: @VaoTsun: that will not work. The check for the length is done before the trigger is executed.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to write that into a table. But you can configure Postgres to log all failed statements to the Postgres logfile.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes - true. maybe rule then?..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's great! Any guides on how to?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Comment: @mrbTT rule would be incedible wheel here. maybe better create a function fn_insert(rowtype) that has an exception handling and instead of performing the insert select from that `fn_insert`?..

Comment: Another option is [pgAudit](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pgaudit)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here is to write a function that catches any errors during `INSERT` and performs the alternative instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_insert(p_name text, p_surname text) RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   INSERT INTO testtable (name, surname)
      VALUES (p_name, p_surname);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      INSERT INTO log_failed_inserts(failedname, failedsurname)
         VALUES (p_name, p_surname);
END;$$;
```

If you don't want a function, you could use a `DO` statement:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
   INSERT ...
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      INSERT ...
END;$$;
```

That has the disadvantage that you cannot pass parameters to it.

The third solutions is to explicitly use savepoints in SQL:

```
BEGIN;
SAVEPOINT sp1;
INSERT INTO test_table ...;
```

If there is no error, proceed with

```
COMMIT;
```

If there is an error:

```
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT sp1;
INSERT INTO log_failed_inserts ...;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: That's a way to do it, but what really is doing the `INSERT` is a java application :/

Comment: You didn't say that. I have added more solutions, one of them should work for you.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe So is this not possible to be done via triggers? The reason I'm interested in doing it via triggers is that if anybody runs an insert command directly on the table by mistake, without running the do_insert function, it still ends up adding a row in the log_failed_inserts.

Comment: No, because the length is checked *before* a `BEFORE` trigger is invoked.